# Unable to Login with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm currently doing a project with `Symfony VERSION = '2.5.10'`. Everything's working fine until we changed our database and update its entities. I already tried different ways yet still I can't log in to the system. Whenever I run on either prod or dev environment, it gives me this error:

> **Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem**

I already tried clearing the cache manually or even through command prompt, even tried running these commands:

`php app\console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`

`php app\console doctrine:schema:update --force`

And even tried creating a new user using this:

`php app\console fos:user:create testuser test@example.com p@ssw0rd`

and it successfully saved in the database.

Here's the log file:

```
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SaveSessionListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelTerminate". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SaveSessionListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SaveSessionListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelTerminate". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelTerminate". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SaveSessionListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelTerminate". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt" (parameters: "_controller": "web_profiler.controller.profiler:toolbarAction", "token": "d950df", "_route": "_wdt") [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SaveSessionListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
[2015-07-02 08:24:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelTerminate". [] []
```

Could you please tell me what's wrong with what I'm doing? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I tried clearing the cookies and run the application again and found this on the logs:

```
[2015-07-03 04:27:34] request.INFO: Matched route "fos_user_security_check" (parameters: "_controller": "FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController::checkAction", "_route": "fos_user_security_check") [] []
[2015-07-03 04:27:34] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.username AS username1, t0.username_canonical AS username_canonical2, t0.email AS email3, t0.email_canonical AS email_canonical4, t0.enabled AS enabled5, t0.salt AS salt6, t0.password AS password7, t0.last_login AS last_login8, t0.locked AS locked9, t0.expired AS expired10, t0.expires_at AS expires_at11, t0.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token12, t0.password_requested_at AS password_requested_at13, t0.roles AS roles14, t0.credentials_expired AS credentials_expired15, t0.credentials_expire_at AS credentials_expire_at16, t0.ediUserId AS ediUserId17 FROM edi_user t0 WHERE t0.username_canonical = ? LIMIT 1 ["erosales"] []
[2015-07-03 04:27:34] security.INFO: Authentication request failed: An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.username AS username1, t0.username_canonical AS username_canonical2, t0.email AS email3, t0.email_canonical AS email_canonical4, t0.enabled AS enabled5, t0.salt AS salt6, t0.password AS password7, t0.last_login AS last_login8, t0.locked AS locked9, t0.expired AS expired10, t0.expires_at AS expires_at11, t0.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token12, t0.password_requested_at AS password_requested_at13, t0.roles AS roles14, t0.credentials_expired AS credentials_expired15, t0.credentials_expire_at AS credentials_expire_at16, t0.ediUserId AS ediUserId17 FROM edi_user t0 WHERE t0.username_canonical = ? LIMIT 1' with params ["erosales"]: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.ediUserId' in 'field list' [] []
[2015-07-03 04:27:34] security.DEBUG: Redirecting to /login [] []
```

I already rendered a couple of hours trying to fix this but still I can't. I hope someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? Search for the exception and where it's thrown and set a breakpoint to inspect the data (or do some good old var_dump-ing). From the message I assume it's a `Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Exception/AuthenticationServiceException`. Look for any database calls where the exception is used and investigate those db-accesses.

Comment: Ok I will, thanks for the interest.

Comment: Since you can create a new user from the command line, I assume your db-access is still working, so it's probably some stupid stuff like wrong results from a query, e.g. due to encoding differences. Look into your UserAuthProvider and see if the retrieved user contains all the right data. See: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6a2d3a4aec75853d0799893c6cd843e398f975a9/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php#L80

Comment: I'm still not really very much familiar with this since it's my first time to use this framework, but I'll try to investigate and follow what you've said. Thanks @dbrumann

Comment: The error is clear: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.ediUserId' in 'field list'` it seems that doctrine is unable to find the column editUserId in your database. It should be edi_user_id (doctrine use snake case for the column name and camelCase for the entity property). Can you show us your `edi_user` entity?

Comment: As Coussinsky correctly suggests, you need a property in the EdiUser Entity. The table t0 is "FROM edi_user t0" and there a property ediUserId is needed. Anyway, consider upgrading your Symfony installation that currently is at version 2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement

> Everything's working fine until we changed our database

and

> Unknown column 't0.ediUserId'

may point to a not executed migration that is missing in the db. Have a look at "migrations_version" table and compare. This is of course only if using migrations bundle.

The other thing might be a typo in here `ediUserId`.